# Prolog pack_install SSL Error to swi-prolog.org

Tags: module, download, installation, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question:

I am trying to run a prolog file, that uses the prolog-library [delay](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=delay). So it has at some place in the beginning the following line:

```
:- use_module(library(delay)).
```

When starting that file, Prolog tells me

```
source_link `library(delay)` does not exist
Goal (directive) failed: atoms:use_module(library(delay))
```

So I thought, maybe I need to install that library manually, first. So I ran `?- pack_install(delay)`

But that returned

```
% Contacting server at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ...
ERROR: SSL(14090086) ssl3_get_server_certificate: certificate verify failed
```

I have no idea how to proceed and google is not helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem connecting to the server offering the package.

It actually works for me:

```
% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
Install delay@0.3.3 from http://storage.googleapis.com/packs.ndrix.com/delay/delay-0.3.3.zip Y/n?
```

What is your Prolog version?

Can you download the pack directly. Either using the browser or `wget`/`curl`:

```
wget http://storage.googleapis.com/packs.ndrix.com/delay/delay-0.3.3.zip
```

The above is a zipfile of the repository https://github.com/mndrix/delay/

I suppose you can just put file `delay/prolog/delay.pl` onto the Prolog library search path.

Comment: my prolog version is 7.2.3 for amd64

Comment: @Jere I'm not sure whether that has to do with anything (it should not) but if it doesn't work, why not try with the 8.1?

Comment: @Jere It's IT! You never know what can not happen in the next minute. (And if it doesn't you better be [Crazy Prepared](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrazyPrepared))